# Newbie. calling something in kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to call "start" from the AUDIO screen

```
class Audio(Screen):

    def start(self):

class MainPage(Screen):

    def open1(self, *args):
         self.play = ImageButton(source= 'play.png',allow_stretch= True, pos= (600, 850), size_hint= (.2,.1))
         self.play.bind(on_press=audio.start()) #How do I call start?
```

EDIT: This is just a sample code

Comment: is your `start(self)` method defined? According to your code it is not. In addition, keep in mind that you should have a ScreenManager.

Comment: yes 'start(self)' is defined and I have a screen manager. The code is just a sample, Thank you.... I just want to know how to call a method from another screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you should define this methods in your screen manager root. For example:

```
class RootScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    # your class implementation
    def start(self):
       # your method implementation

class Audio(Screen):
    def start(self):
        # your code

class MainPage(Screen):
    # your code
```

If this method is called when pressing a button, I strongly suggest to use a Kivy file to define your view, and you can call `start` using the `on_press` attribute:

```
Button:
    Image:
        source: 'play.png'
    size_hint: .2, .1
    on_press: app.root.start()
    pos: 600, 850
```

On the other hand, if you don't want the previous approach you can create an instance of the class within the method you want to called is defined, and then bind that method with your button by:

```
instance = Audio()
self.play.bind(on_press=instance.start)
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer gave me the idea to keep everything in one screen.

Comment: @RashIsh, I'm glad my answer help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of a class before you can call its methods.

In Python it's done by calling the class with trailing parenthesis, basically just like a method call.
With that said, change your last line from:

```
self.play.bind(on_press=audio.start())
```

to this:

```
self.play.bind(on_press=Audio().start())
```